# how to debug kernel loading and intrd load in virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, virtualbox

I have cloned the linux kernel repo on my arch hosted machine (host is ubuntu 16.04). Two weeks ago I was able to boot into the new kernel (it was 4.11.rc06 back then), then I did git pull and recompiled everything and it just hangs after "loading initial ramdisk image...".

So I tried `git clean -xfd` then `make localmoduleconfig` answering defaults for everything, then `make` then `make modules_install` then `mkinitcpio -p linux.4.11.custom` and of course `sudo cp -v arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-linux.4.11.custom`.

After I verified it does indeed hang I tried more git pulls, more cleans, but nothing changed.

Running the same kernel from the same source on a real machine boots. 
I could not find recorded bug in virtualbox or find an update for ubuntu.

Next I tried debugging it myself by adding to the grub's linux command: `debug earlyprintk=vga,keep` and even removing the initrd line adding noinitrd to the kernel, but I get no error. Just a screen with the grub's "echo" messages that stays like that forever.

1. How can I debug it?
2. Has anyone got any idea what can be done?

Comment: I guess people get mislead by your title. Instead of complaining ("virtualbox not working") ask the question in the title ("how to debug Linux kernel boot sequence?") and elaborate in the body of the question.

Comment: n.m. proposition accepted.

Comment: Can you see kernel/init messages passed through system uart (or whatever you use as a default console)?

Comment: i used the virtual console, it's not embedded device so i found it pointless to use serial. i see nothing, i walked over all kernel debug options and still nothing. i tried to get version 4.11.0rc8 and it still works ok, only in the final version and 4.12.rc01 it wont boot. i don't actually have a problem  with not booting, i have a problem with me not being able to see why.

Comment: You seem to think it's a kernel problem, but why do you think it even gets to booting the kernel? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting

Comment: what evidence u see from my post that it doesn't boot ?

Comment: i don't know it it's related, but when installing virtualbox dkms source package 22.1 (newest) with kernel 12-rc0 i can't compile it, the alloc-r0drv-linux fail to build due to implicit functions declarations (change of interface \ functions ?)

Comment: @codeScriber The last message you see is "loading initial ramdisk image...", which is actually a GRUB message, AFAIK. So there is no evidence of any kernel activity.

Comment: @ErkiA ok, any idea how can i debug that, if u ask me grub loads the initrd to memory and jumps to the start address and hangs there, if i'll make more "echo"s from the grub u are right i'll see them, but for example adding explicit boot command doesn't help as well. Also as i wrote before trying to  compile the virtualbox kernel drivers fails with this kernel which makes me suspect even more a vb - kernel issue.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether the kernel even starts I would use KDB (kernel's built-in debugger), and see if you get a prompt at startup.

For better debugging I would try to get KGDB (GDB for kernel) working.

You can actually activate both to have all options available. See following link for more information about this:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kgdb/index.html

Comment: nice idea, the issue was 100% virtualbox since that kernel worked fine in regular PC arch and vmware player.